# TestNG: Multiple suite files are not running but single xml file is running multiple times

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

This is my testng.xml file:

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" parallel="true" thread-count="5">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="xml-files/live.xml"></suite-file>
        <suite-file path="xml-files/test.xml"></suite-file>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

I want to run both these xml and though it does start running  but the problem is, it only runs single file(**test.xml**) two times. does anyone have idea why is it happening?

***Update: Added pom, live and test.xml files***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.hiverqa</groupId>
<artifactId>hiverqa</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>hiverqa</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
        <version>7.14.5</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

live.xml

```
<parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>

<parameter name="isExtensionInstalled" value="true" />
<parameter name="profileEnvironment" value="Live" /> <!-- default is selenium browser,Use 'Test' for test environment -->
<test name="SM Onboarding with Extension Test">


    <classes>
        <class name="tests.Onboarding_NonMP_SM_WebSignUP" />
        <class name="tests.Onboarding_NonMP_SL_SignUP" />
        <class name="tests.Onboarding_MP_SM_Signup" />
    </classes>



</test> <!-- Test -->
```

test.xml

```
<parameter name="isExtensionInstalled" value="true" />
<parameter name="profileEnvironment" value="Test" /> <!-- default is selenium browser,Use 'Test' for test environment -->
<test name="SM Onboarding with Extension Test">


    <classes>
        <class name="tests.Onboarding_NonMP_SM_WebSignUP" />
        <class name="tests.Onboarding_NonMP_SL_SignUP" />
        <class name="tests.Onboarding_MP_SM_Signup" />
    </classes>



</test> <!-- Test -->
```

Comment: Can you add the some more code like All 3 xml files ?

Comment: @NarendraR I have only two xmls to run. the problem is that when i try to run these files, last xml runs multiple times. do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to configure `live.xml` file and `test.xml` file in your `pom.xml` file using `maven-surefire-plugin`. You can do it in following way after your `</dependencies>` tag.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>"xml-files/live.xml"</suiteXmlFile>
                    <suiteXmlFile>"xml-files/test.xml"</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then next you can run your `testng.xml` as it is..

Comment: i've tried that too but it did not work. It runs test.xml(last suite file) multiple times.

Comment: can you show your test.xml file live.xml file pom file and testng.xml file?

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: In your pom file you have configured your tesng.xml file two times, is there any reason for that? `<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</properties>` and `<configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>`

Comment: Yes, its intended. Basically, i'm referring testng.xml file from <properties> tag.

Comment: @pritesh could you provide the output that shows test.xml got executed twice

Answer (score 0):

You can try below approach which will help you execute to run multiple testNg.xml file together

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.TestNG;

public class TestNGRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//Place all your multiple testng.xml suit file this progarm will it'self take care and execute one by one in single go of execution 
        String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/src/test/resources/testRunners";

        File directory = new File(currentDir);

        File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();
        List<String> suitFiles = new ArrayList<>();

        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            suitFiles.add(currentDir + "/" + file.getName());
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }

        TestNG runner = new TestNG();
        runner.setTestSuites(suitFiles);

        runner.run();

    }

}
```